# Apache Cloudstack XCP-ng 20.04 Volume Snapshot Failed

Tags: snapshot, cloudstack, xcp-ng

I am using **Apache CloudStack v 4.16** with **XCP-ing** center **20.04.01**. While trying to take a snapshot of my volume, the below error is logged in my XCP-in center and the volume snapshot creation is getting failed.

Why do I get this error and how can I prevent it?

```
[error||10737525 ||backtrace] Async.host.call_plugin R:07603c920ee8 failed with exception Se
rver_error(XENAPI_PLUGIN_FAILURE, [ mountNfsSecondaryStorage; SROSError; Error reporting error, unknown key Unexpected error while tr
ying to mount 10.1.1.20:/data/cloudstack-secondary/ to /var/cloud_mount/0bf8e8c8-f9b7-3602-962d-456drf4567ff ])
```

```
[error||10737525 ||backtrace] Raised Server_error(XENAPI_PLUGIN_FAILURE, [ mountNfsSecondary
Storage; SROSError; Error reporting error, unknown key Unexpected error while trying to mount 10.1.1.20:/data/cloudstack-secondary to
 /var/cloud_mount/0bf8e8c8-f9b7-3602-962d-456drf4567ff ])
```

```
[error||10737525 ||backtrace] 1/1 xapi Raised at file (Thread 10737525 has no backtrace table. Was with_backtraces called?, line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing a NFS version in global setting 'secstorage.nfs.version' and restarting mgmt servers resolved the issue.

Looks like nfs version was passed to xenserver as 'NULL' and the xcp-ng failed to mount it due to invalid parameters